# How to access csv file in the root folder of the Google Colaboratory?

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I am trying to access a CSV file uploaded right in the same folder that my python notebook is from the colaboratory.

when I simply do :

```
pd.read_csv("train.csv")
```

It throws me : "File b'train.csv' does not exist" error.

Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code snippet?

Comment: Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744131/colaboratory-i-can-access-to-my-google-drive-folder-and-file) for recipes to access files either locally or on Drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Colaboratory: i can access to my google drive folder and file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744131/colaboratory-i-can-access-to-my-google-drive-folder-and-file)

Answer (score 0):

When you upload the file. It's not saved in the current folder.

```
uploaded = files.upload()
```

It's stored as the value in the `uploaded` dictionary, with the filename as key.