# Creating a Spark RDD from a file located in Google Drive using Python on Colab.Research.Google

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I have been successful in running Python 3 / Spark 2.2.1 program in Google's Colab.Research platform :

```
!apt-get update
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget -q http://apache.osuosl.org/spark/spark-2.2.1/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!tar xf spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!pip install -q findspark

import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7"

import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
```

this works perfectly when I uploaded text files from my local computer to the Unix VM using

```
from google.colab import files
datafile = files.upload()
```

and read them as follows :

```
textRDD = spark.read.text('hobbit.txt').rdd
```

### so far so good ..

My problem starts when I am trying to read a file that is lying in my Google drive colab directory.

Following instructions I have authenticated user and created a drive service

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')
```

after which I have been able to access the file lying in the drive as follows :

```
file_id = '1RELUMtExjMTSfoWF765Hr8JwNCSL7AgH'

import io
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
downloaded = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(downloaded, request)
done = False
while done is False:
  # _ is a placeholder for a progress object that we ignore.
  # (Our file is small, so we skip reporting progress.)
  _, done = downloader.next_chunk()

downloaded.seek(0)
print('Downloaded file contents are: {}'.format(downloaded.read()))

Downloaded file contents are: b'The king beneath the mountain\r\nThe king of ......
```

even this works perfectly ..

```
downloaded.seek(0)
print(downloaded.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

and gets the data

```
The king beneath the mountain
The king of carven stone
The lord of silver fountain ...
```

where things FINALLY GO WRONG is where I try to grab this data and put it into a spark RDD

```
downloaded.seek(0)
tRDD = spark.read.text(downloaded.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

and I get the error ..

```
AnalysisException: 'Path does not exist: file:/content/The king beneath the mountain\ ....
```

Evidently, I am not using the correct method / parameters to read the file into spark. I have tried quite a few of the methods described

I would be very grateful if someone can help me figure out how to read this file for subsequent processing.

Comment: You can start by asking what does [spark.read.text()](https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-spark/read-input-text-file-to-rdd-example/) command accept as arguments. It says in the documents that it reads "HDFS/local file system/any hadoop supported file system URI" none of which seem to be related to drive api.

Comment: so i was hoping that there would be some other method with which i can read the data. would be grateful if someone can suggest an alternative method

Answer (score 1):

A complete solution to this problem is available in another StackOverflow question that is available [at this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744131/colaboratory-can-i-access-to-my-google-drive-folder-and-file).

Here is the [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1srw_HFWQ2SMgmWIawucXfusGzrj1_U0q&scrollTo=c99EvWo1s9-x) where this solution is demonstrated.

I have tested it and it works!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `spark.read.text` expects a file name. But you give it the file content instead. You can try either of these:

- save it to a file then give the name
- use just `downloaded` instead of `downloaded.read().decode('utf-8')`

You can also simplify downloading from Google Drive with pydrive. I gave an example here.

https://gist.github.com/korakot/d56c925ff3eccb86ea5a16726a70b224

Downloading is just

```
fid = drive.ListFile({'q':"title='hobbit.txt'"}).GetList()[0]['id']
f = drive.CreateFile({'id': fid})
f.GetContentFile('hobbit.txt')
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid writing the file into the VM disk and then reading it again into spark ... but if nothing else is possible, will use that