# Accessing drive files in Google Colab

Tags: python, drive, google-colaboratory

I need to get access to a dataset of images (600MB dataset) in Google Colab.

I already uploaded all of my project files in my drive. The problem is that it seems that Google Colab is not recognizing data_config.py which is as file with all the functions that I need to get my datasets.

What should I do to use my data_config.py?

[Error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6KPi.png)

Comment: Please post your relevant code and complete error messages as text, not images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Colaboratory: Can I access to my Google drive folder and file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744131/colaboratory-can-i-access-to-my-google-drive-folder-and-file)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please proofread and properly format your questions. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744131/colaboratory-can-i-access-to-my-google-drive-folder-and-file this can help u