# Making an existing director of Python programs available to Colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a number of directories of Python programs what I would like to execute on Colaboratory.  Is there a way to do that -- other than to load and save the files one-by-one? If it helps, the directories are all in my own Google Drive. So all I would need (I think) is a way to `cd` to a given directory. I tried `!cd ..`, which presumably should go to my top Google Drive directory, but it doesn't seem to work.

Just copied a directory into `Google Drive\Colab Notebooks` using the file explorer. But Colab refused to `cd` to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to mount your Google Drive before files contained therein will be available in Colab.

A recipe for how to mount Drive is available in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47744465/8841057

Answer (score 0):

After you mount the drive, don’t use `!cd`.

Use `%cd` instead.