# How to include the MSRA 10K dataset in google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have the msra 10k dataset downloaded but I don't know how to include the dataset in google colab. Either I want to upload the dataset directly from my pc or use any links to feed it google colab but it's not working.

from google.colab import files

```
import io
import os

uploaded = files.upload()
```

Answer (score 2):

welcome to Stack Overflow! You can upload the dataset to your Google Drive, and then have Collab access it from there.

Here's a StackOverflow answer that helps you do just that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50888878/4283749

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For google drive, it is now easier to use the built-in mount function.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Your drive content is now in `drive/My Drive`. You can list them

```
!ls drive/My\ Drive
```

You can also see the directory contents using the "Left Pane" > "Files Tab"

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `wget` to download it directly into Colab.

`!wget http://mftp.mmcheng.net/Data/MSRA10K_Imgs_GT.zip`