# Open ipynb file from the list of files mounted from drive

Tags: google-drive-api, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have mounted my google drive to colab. I can see the documents i need in the files panel. I would like to open the .ipynb files listed in the drive, so i can view and run them in colab. This seems like a very trivial thing, but i can't see an easy way of just opening them directly. If i double click it downloads the notebook. Is there an easy way of just opening the file directly from this list?

Thanks in advance for any help
[image of the google drive list of files here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kN9R.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Colaboratory: Can I access to my Google drive folder and file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744131/colaboratory-can-i-access-to-my-google-drive-folder-and-file)

Answer (score 2):

The file browser in your screenshot will show the raw notebook JSON.

In order to open the notebooks, use the browser at http://drive.google.com/ and navigate to your Colab notebooks folder.

Or, you can click this link to show all of your Colab notebooks in Drive --

https://drive.google.com/drive/search?q=owner:me%20(type:application/vnd.google.colaboratory%20||%20type:application/vnd.google.colab)

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! I have found a better way for my particular case - i just access the .ipynb directly from GitHub rather than using google drive at all. But i can see now this is the best way to do it via Drive - so thanks again.