# Problem accessing a .csv file on Colab using python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have mounted my google drive on to Colab and yet am unable to access a .csv file using Python. I've imported pandas here:

import pandas as pd

```
data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Capstone 3/country_vaccinations.csv')
print(data)
```

Also, if I try to open the file by double-clicking it directly, it says

```
"Error Could not fetch country_vaccinations.csv from backend"
```

Please let me know if you have any thoughts on this or could point me to a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Colaboratory: Can I access to my Google drive folder and file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744131/colaboratory-can-i-access-to-my-google-drive-folder-and-file)

Answer (score 0):

To mount your Google drive to Colab:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

and then to cd to any directory in the Google drive:

```
import os
os.chdir("drive/My Drive/<your-folder>")
```

and to list all items in the directory that Colab is working on (to make sure it's the right dir):

```
!ls
```

Answer (score 0):

Mount the Google drive into Colab:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

You will have to paste the authorization token in the box provided.

Then copy the path of the csv file from the right hand navigator;

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(full_path)
```