# Accessing public google drive file from python colab

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I have the following link:

`https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXXX/view?usp=sharing`

It's a csv file, with public access which i want to use as a dataset.

I don't know it's name, i want to access it and read it's content simple as possible.

This notebook should run in different environments should it download the file on execution.

I've tried `pydrive` but the authentication was a mess.

Quick help would be appreciated, snippets are welcome

Comment: [this will help](https://towardsdatascience.com/different-ways-to-connect-google-drive-to-a-google-colab-notebook-pt-1-de03433d2f7a) and [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744131/colaboratory-can-i-access-to-my-google-drive-folder-and-file)

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. I need first to download those files into my google drive and don't know how to do that. Any quick snippet would be appreciated!
Pandas also didn't work well because it didn't handle correctly with the custom format of my files.